# Error every time I try to open Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

Every time I try to open Visual Studio 2010 I get this error:

```
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01:   devenv.exe
Problem Signature 02:   10.0.40219.1
Problem Signature 03:   4d5f2a73
Problem Signature 04:   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Collaboration.Microsoft
Problem Signature 05:   10.0.41206.0
Problem Signature 06:   4edeeb8c
Problem Signature 07:   49
Problem Signature 08:   0
Problem Signature 09:   System.InvalidCastException
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Locale ID:  1033
```

I already repair the installation with the installation disk, but still the same error.

I have installed in my machine, Visual Studio 2012 Pro and works fine, It seems to be something related with Team Foundation service. Also It happens when I just open it, it shows me the start screen then I got this error.

this is my VS information:
Yes as far as I know, the version is Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

```
Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.50709 SP1Rel

Installed Version: Professional

Microsoft Office Developer Tools   01018-532-2002102-70203
Microsoft Office Developer Tools

Microsoft Visual Basic 2010   01018-532-2002102-70203
Microsoft Visual Basic 2010

Microsoft Visual C# 2010   01018-532-2002102-70203
Microsoft Visual C# 2010

Microsoft Visual C++ 2010   01018-532-2002102-70203
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010

Microsoft Visual F# 2010   01018-532-2002102-70203
Microsoft Visual F# 2010

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer   01018-532-2002102-70203
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer

Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010   01018-532-2002102-70203
Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010

Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0   
Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0


Crystal Reports Templates for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010   
Crystal Reports Templates for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2529927)   KB2529927
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2529927.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2542054)   KB2542054
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2542054.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2548139)   KB2548139
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2548139.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2549864)   KB2549864
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2549864.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2635973)   KB2635973
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2635973.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2736182)   KB2736182
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2736182.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2813041)   KB2813041
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2813041.

InstallShield Limited Edition   
InstallShield. For more information visit the Flexera Software website at <http://www.FlexeraSoftware.com>. Copyright © 2012 Flexera Software LLC. All Rights Reserved.

JetBrains ReSharper 8   build 8.0.14.856 on 2013-07-18T02:49:56 [Not Loaded]
JetBrains ReSharper 8 package for Microsoft Visual Studio. For more information about ReSharper, visit http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/. Copyright © 2003–2013 JetBrains, Inc.

Microsoft Recipe Framework Package   8.0
This package provides services to the guidance packages.

Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools   10.0.41206.0
Power Tools that extend the Team Foundation Server integration with Visual Studio.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU Service Pack 1 (KB983509)   KB983509
This service pack is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this service pack will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint Developer Tools   10.0.40219
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint Developer Tools

Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2644980)   KB2644980
This security update is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this security update will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2644980.

Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2645410)   KB2645410
This security update is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this security update will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2645410.

SlowCheetah - XML config transforms    1.0
This package enables you to transform your app.config or any other XML file based on the build configuration. It also adds additional tooling to help you create XML transforms.

Telerik WebUI VSExtensions   2013.2.611.0
Telerik RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX VSExtensions Package

SQL Prompt 6
For more information about SQL Prompt, see the Red Gate website at
http://www.red-gate.com
For customer support, call 1-866-733-4283.
Copyright © 2006–2009 Red Gate Software Ltd
```

Any Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried running `devenv /safemode` from a developer command prompt? If that works try a `devenv /resetsettings /resetaddin`.  If you still can't get it running try a full uninstall/reinstall.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ran the VS2010 in safemode(as @RichardBanks suggested) and worked (I closed and opened again normally and worked too), now I realized that the problem come back when I click on the TFS tab and try to connect, any clue?

Comment: Question: Have you applied all the latest Visual Studio service packs?

Comment: I updated my post in order to bring my VS instance details @RichardBanks

Comment: All I can suggest is that you disable/uninstall your extensions and add-ins to try and isolate which one is causing the problem. I'd start with the power tools, then ReSharper and progress from there. It's a bit of a pain, but most likely there are two add-ins/extensions that are conflicting with each other.

Answer (score 0):

I got this type of error, when a specific visual studio update has been installed.
When I did an uninstall of this update (I just guessed by date, which it might be), everything was ok again.

I do not know, if this is a random problem, or tied to a specific update, though.

Update: I found the update in question: KB2813041. It's evil.
Update: Another one, making trouble: KB2736182.